# WP Multi Site - configure Sub domain pointing to parent sub directory

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I've a purchased a hosting plan from hostinger, but it seems they don't provide wild card subdomains. Now I want to set up a multisite wp on hostinger in a subdomain format, not sub directories. When I set up multisite as sub-directories, it works fine, but it is not working for Subdomain format. I think it can be fixed by modifying the htaccess. Need your help to fix this. Here is the domain structure -

Parent domain - example.com [ Directory - user/domains/example.com/public_html/(wp files)]

Sub domain - abc.example.com [Directory - user/domains/example.com/public_html/abc]

Now if a request comes to abc.example.com, how can I redirect the request to parent domain so that WP can recognize and serve the files as Multisite.

example.com .htaccess -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Regardless of whether the host supports "wildcard" subdomains, you should still be able to configure the subdomain to point wherever you want (if not, then this is a very limiting factor imposed by Hostinger?!).

Comment: What configuration should I make to my subdomain so that it can be picked by multisite main installation? Currently if I navigate to my subdomain, it is picking up the files from that subdirectory. I think it can be resolved if I could point the subdomain to main site directory, but there is no way to do that. Is there any alternate to do that? May be by modifying htacess? I'm bit confused.

Comment: If abc.example.com and example.com are both to be run from the same WordPress installation (ie, how Multisite is supposed to work), then you shouldn't need to have anything in the `.../abc` directory. Also, for the `.htaccess` file, see https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ .